# Hibernate foreign key without reference to foreign key Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I use Hibernate 4.2.
I have two tables say Employee and Employer. I have employer_id in employee table as foreign key.

Now in Employee.java file can I have

```
@Column(name="employer_id") 
private Integer employerId;
```

I don't want to have a Employer reference in Employee as I don't want to fetch Employer data every time I fetch employee.

Also please let me know is there a way I can have Employer reference and make Hibernate not to fetch it unless an request is made say getEmployer();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using lazy loading put following annotation:

```
private Employer employer;
.
.
.

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="employer_id")
public Employer getEmployer() {
   return this.employer;
}
```

And employer will be loaded only when you call `getEmployer()`

Comment: Hi...I have other fields in Employee as well....And is being frequently fetched from database.
In lazy whenever it also fetches the information form employer when I fetch some other employee.

The employer_id in my case is not much used and being used in only very few scenarios.

Hence I think to use lazy will also won't serve mine actual purpose of not having to fetch employer data from db.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you meant! This won't fetch data unless you call the getter method. If you call getter you need it though!

Comment: Thanks for response.
Just a doubt...It won't fetch employer details, if I fetch some other details from employee say employee.getDepartmentDetails();